# How prove this inequality with strange condition $n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-3)^2=x^2_{1}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_{i}\ge 0，n\ge 3 $,and such
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-3)^2=x^2_{1}$$
 show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n+1)x_{i}}{n}}\ge 3n$$

I found this inequality when $x_{i}=\dfrac{3n}{n+1}$ then  the inequality have $=$,

because
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-3)^2=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{9}{(n+1)^2}=\dfrac{9n^2}{(n+1)^2}=x^2_{1}$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n+1)x_{i}}{n}}=3n$$
so How prove this inequality?Thanks

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: where did you get this bad boi???

Comment: If I am not wrong, $n=2$, $x_1=6$ and $x_2=0$ is a counter-example.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{x_i}\ge n\sqrt{\dfrac{3n}{n+1}}$

Comment: @Kelenner,Hello,sorry, if $n\ge 3$?

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is true.

Putting up the restriction under the form $$\sum_{i=2}^n(x_i-3)^2=(\frac 1n-1)x_1^2+6x_1-9=f_n(x_1)$$ we must have $$(1-\frac 1n)x_1^2-6x_1+9\le 0$$ from which we can deduce that the more $n$ grows the less the possibilities in order to have $x_1$ non-negative. Note that when $n$ tends to infinity the possibilities for $x_1$ are reduced to the single point $x_1 = 3$ in which case all $x_i$ must be equal to $3$ which is clear. By plotting some of these quadratic trinomials shown in the next figure (*graphs of $-f_n(x_1)$ for $n=3,4,10$ and $100$* ) you can see this clearly.

[image]

Analytically the maximum value taken by $f_n(x_1)$  is $M_n=\dfrac{9}{n-1}$
and the interval  of possible values for $x_1$ is $I_n=\left[\dfrac{3(n-\sqrt n)}{n-1},\dfrac{3(n+\sqrt n)}{n-1}\right]$ from which $0\le f_n(x_1)\le\dfrac{9}{n-1}$.

(*Note that $I_n\supsetneq I_{n+1}$ and $(\cap I_n)_{n\to\infty}=\{3\}$*)

The proposed inequality 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n+1)x_{i}}{n}}=\sqrt{\frac{3(n+1)}{n}}\left[\sqrt x_1+\sqrt x_2+....\sqrt x_n\right]\ge 3n$$ suggests looking at the minimum of $\sqrt x_2+\sqrt x_3+....\sqrt x_n$.

The condition (*an $(n-1)$-sphere*) $$\sum_{i=2}^n(x_i-3)^2=\big(\sqrt{f_n(x_1)}\big)^2$$ determines that the minimum of $\sqrt x_2+....\sqrt x_n$ occurs when $x_2=x_3=...=x_n=\sqrt{\dfrac{f_(x_1)}{n-1}}+3$
so one has $$\sqrt{\frac{3(n+1)}{n}}[\sqrt x_1+\sqrt x_2+....\sqrt x_n]\ge\sqrt{\frac{3(n+1)}{n}}\left[\sqrt x_1+(n-1)\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{f_(x_1)}{n-1}}+3\right)\right]$$ Therefore, because of $$\begin{cases}\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n+1)}{n}}\gt\sqrt3\\\sqrt{x_1}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n-\sqrt n)}{n-1}}\\\sqrt{\dfrac{f_n(x_1)}{n-1}}\ge 0\end{cases}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{3(n+1)}{n}}[\sqrt x_1+\sqrt x_2+....\sqrt x_n]\ge\sqrt3\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{3(n-\sqrt n)}{n-1}}+3(n-1)\right)\ge3\sqrt3(n-1)$$ It is quite easy to verify that for $n\ge3$ one has$$3\sqrt3(n-1)\ge 3n$$ which ends the proof.

Comment: @Batominovski: Thanks you very much.